# OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials get user id

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I am using [Identity Server 3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) and following example from [here.](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/SampleAspNetWebApi) Client Credentials using OAuth 2.0.

I overwritten AuthorizeAttribute but when I look at the ClaimsIdentity **Name** and **Actor** are null. Is this by design? I am responsible to populate them? If so how? I see that **Claims** has **client_id** but why it's not getting reflected in **Name** or **Actor**?

**Q: How can I get identity of who is calling?**

[image: actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity]

Answer (score 1):

We have two definition in OAuth, **User** and **Client**

**User** is a human participant which basically has username and password.

**Client** is an application which User use which has a `client_Id` and `client_secret`.

When you using Client Credentials there is no User involved, and only clientId and ClientSecret is sent, therefor both `Actor` and `Name` property is null, because these properties are bind to user. In this case you should use **Password**, **Code** or **Implicit** Grant Type which have user involved.

Comment: well if 2 API's communicate and they use client_credential flow between eachother. Shouldn't the second APi that is called by the first also have the user somehow integrated? I mean lets say i call an orderService, the orderService should only be able to get resources that are connected to that user @kahbazi